# Lowercase in facets search api

Tags: search

I have an issue with **Facets on search API** (Solr Integration).

- Facets items are all in lowercase, and thats not how the content type save them, and I've made a query to solr server directly and the index items there have uppercase letters

can someone help me ?

Thx

Comment: Which filters have you enabled on this index?

Comment: Tokenizer and Stopwords

Answer (score 4):

You could use *hook_facetapi_filters()* to define a new filter for your facets.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_facetapi_filter().
 */
function MODULE_facetapi_filters() {
  return array(
    'uppercase_items' => array(
      'handler' => array(
        'label' => t('Uppercase items'), 
        'class' => 'FacetapiFilterUppercaseItems',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

and then extend the *FacetapiFilter* class like this:

```
class FacetapiFilterUppercaseItems extends FacetapiFilter {

  /**
   * Filters facet items.
   */
  public function execute(array $build) {
    // Do your magic.
    foreach ($build as $key => $value) {
      $build[$key]['#markup'] = ucfirst($value['#markup']);
    }
    return $build;
  }

  /**
   * Adds hook documentation.
   */
  function settingsForm(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['uppercase_items'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Uppercase filters'),
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => TRUE,
    );
  }     
}
```

I haven't actually tried this out but this is pretty much what [Facet API Bonus](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus/) does, which is also a great example for creating your own filters.

Answer (score 0):

If your fields are of type "fulltext" (or a variant of fulltext), the captialization may be getting stripped out by an "ignore case" processor in Solr or in Search API.

You can add the same field again, but a) Drill down to the "Name" field using the (+) sign next to the field as you add it (e.g. Authored by » User » Name),  and b) Choose type "String" for the field. Then use that field for your facet, instead of the first one. The facet label should then include capitalization, if the field's value is actually capitalized.

Another advantage is that string fields in facets can display multiple words, which may not be the case if you're using fulltext fields.

Comment: I have set the fields to String and they are still returned as all lowercase.